# salesForce : Picklist metadata deployment API Version 40

Tags: deployment, salesforce, version, picklist

When I deploy a picklist’s metadata, If picklist values are missing from a component definition, they get deactivated when deployed. Deactivation occurs only for missing picklist options for for both standard and custom fields.
Any one has any idea how to prevent this not to set deactivate for any missing picklist value?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, update your metadata by adding missing picklist values.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! We cannot add missing values. We have package and different Orgs. may have different picklist values and that local picklist values are deactivating after deployment.

Comment: In such case possible solution - add the relevant picklist values to picklist field in each record type of object and try to deploy the project again. [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gxh5AAA) is the discussion of similar case.